# Can we run cuda accelerated program without toolkit installed?

Tags: c++, dll, cuda, dllimport

I wrote a c++ dll which deals with cuda acceleration and exposed some of its function to use in a c# console application. Everything works fine on my working computer. But i have a problem on another computer:

Working computer: i7 3770 ; Nvidia GT 710 (CUDA Capable) ; CUDA Toolkit: Installed
It works fine on this computer

Another computer: Xeon Octa-core 2.6GHz ; Nvidia Quadro 2000 (GPU-Z program marks it as cuda capable) ; CUDA Toolkit: Not installed

The application (c# console and c++ dll) crashes with error: unable to load dll!

What is the problem with the second computer?
**Main question**: Do you need to install CUDA Toolkit to run a cuda accelerated application?
If yes, then how other applications (Photoshop, etc) do it without CUDA toolkit installed on target computer?

EDIT: I figured out that the program crashed with a simple add function (from DllImport) and not because of the CUDA functions. But everything worked fine on working computer!

Code files:
dllmain.cpp: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_lLmSOVB2AIgXOB-svpCJVQeaJlwQjWI

cudamain.cu: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BkKBEt5Y528phUXNP6lq1UTY7nD8pvxy

Program.cs: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NNTG4fr73ojvGD8qgJdCL2d0HCq2R16n

Comment: You don't need to have the toolkit installed when you merely want to *run* programs compiled for CUDA.  However, you need the CUDA runtime which should be bundled with the NVIDIA driver and obviously needs an NVIDIA grpahics card.  Things like Photoshop most probably do not rely on CUDA but use the more general OpenCL which has broader hardware support.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks for your opinion!  But the program crashes because of a simple add function and says unable to load dll. It works fine on my working computer.

Comment: You didn't give any details. Just saying "it crashed" is not enough. Don't make us guess.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It crashed when the c# console called the add function that was declared using DllImport and was originally in dllmain.cpp! There are no errors on my main computer, but the program crashes on other computer!

Comment: Don't post off site links. Post a [mcve] here. And don't say "it crashed". Provide error message verbatim.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry for off site link, i was getting problems putting the code here. The error message is: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'cudalib.dll': The specific module could not be found. at ConsoleApp.Program.add(Int32 a, Int32 b) at ConsoleApp.Program.Main(String[] args) at line 26 in Program.cs

Comment: The DLL file is in the same folder, and it works fine on main computer.

Comment: So the problem is that the dependencies can't be found. Almost certainly the msvc runtime needed by the dll that you built.

Comment: I will surely try it out. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I finally found the solution! See below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i solved the issue.
**Problem**:
I copied ran following command in command prompt to find the dependencies:
dumpbim /dependents path_to_dll
dependencies were: cudart64_90.dll, VCRUNTIME140.dll, api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll, KERNEL32.dll

dumpbin is application at location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\bin\Hostx64\x64

**Solution**: I just copied the cudart64_90.dll to the application directory.